# Screen-shot is changing colours

Tags: 16.04, browser, colors, screenshot

I have tried to take  Screen-shot of webpage in Browser by many application available for **Ubuntu 16.04**. (e.g. **kazam**, **PrtsS key**,**Alt+PrtSc**, **Shift+PrtSc**,**Screeshot**).

I have also tried **Take a Screenshot** option in Mozila.

All are changing Blue colour to Voilet colour,

What may be the reason of changed colour and how may I resolve this issue?

Thankyou.

Comment: I upload that sreenshot to Skype, here I have no issue, colours were normal here, may be it is a image viewer issue or whatever.    Is there any help for this .

Comment: Is there anything I need to provide to get solution